# Weird behavior in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this simple script that inserts the user's email, and posts into a table. It works and all but it's inserting them incorrectly.

The script:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) == 1) {
    $posts = $_POST["posts"];
    $insert_post = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (email, the_posts) VALUES (:user_id, :posts)");
    $insert_post->bindParam(":user_id", $_SESSION["user_id"]);
    $insert_post->bindParam(":posts", $posts);
    $insert_post->execute();
    echo "<script>alert('Successfully posted!');</script>";
}
```

`$_SESSION["user_id"]` is the user's email. When I submit a post, the email column gets the post and the post column displays the email instead??

Structure of my database:

```
id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT   
email varchar(255) latin1_swedish_ci
the_posts archar(255) latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: Did you echo out the values to ensure that they are indeed what you think they are? Can't see anything obvious about the insert that is wrong.

Comment: can you do var_dump($posts)  ??

Comment: looks fine so either this is not the code or the variables do not contain what you think they do "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. "

Comment: Are the names of your text fields set correctly on your html form?